# Como crear la estructura de datos que DataTables espera con php

Tags: php, jquery, json, datatables, codeigniter-3

De qué manera puedo hacer crear esta estructura de json
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con los datos que obtengo de la siguiente tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso el framework Codeigniter 3 y la arquitectura MVC para agregar mayor contexto.

En mi modelo los datos son llamados:

```
public function getAllPacientes () {
    
    return $this->db->get('pacientes')->result();
}
```

Y en controlador proceso y devuelvo los datos

```
public function getlistpacientes () {
    
    $result = $this->PacienteModel->getAllPacientes();
    $i = 0;

    foreach ($result as $paciente_data) {
        $i++;
        $data = array(
            $paciente_data->id_paciente,
            $paciente_data->nombres_paciente,
            $paciente_data->apellidos_paciente,
            $paciente_data->fecha_nacimiento_paciente,
            $paciente_data->sexo_paciente,
            $paciente_data->telefono_paciente,
            $paciente_data->correo_electronico_paciente,
            'button'
        );
    }

    $columnas['data'] = $data; 

    echo json_encode($columnas);
}
```

Pero en la respuesta solo obtengo un registro, sospecho que sobreescribe una y otra vez el mismo arreglo hasta llegar al último, pero no sé de qué manera hacer que arme y guarde todos los registros tal y como los espera Datatables en la primera imagen.

Comment: Hay alguna funcion que te permita mapear la colleccion que devuelve el query a la BD? Si necesitas mapearlo de esta manera, ahi lo que podes hacer es dejar el array fuera del foreach, crear dinamicamente un objeto del loop, le agregas las propiedades que necesitas, y haces un push al array que tener para hacer el buffer, finalmente agregar este array a la propiedad "data" que espera recibir el DataTable

Answer (score 1):

Efectivamente, estás sobrescribiendo el valor del elemento con clave `data` dentro del array `$columnas`. Puedes solucionarlo reemplazando la línea:

```
$columnas['data'] = $data;
```

Por esta, que se debe incluir dentro del `foreach`:

```
$columnas['data'][] = $data;
```

De este modo `$columnas['data']` funcionará como un array con los datos de los distintos pacientes que recojas del modelo.

Comment: No fue directamente la solución pero me ayudó para encontrarla.
Resulta que al reasignar la variable fuera del bucle siempre mostró un registro, en cambio reasignarla dentro del bucle funcionó como se esperaba


$data[] = array(...);

Comment: Me alegro de que esté resuelto. Perdón, si, se me olvidó indicar que había que incluirla dentro del bucle. En cualquier caso, voy a editar la respuesta por si alguien se encuentra con un problema similar.